# List of custom Class , update view in swift

Tags: swift, list, class, swiftui

I'm new in Swift, sorry for the basic question.

I have created a custom class and I want to display lists of this custom class in SwiftUI. I want to keep track of the changes in this list (new element, element removed). I can not change the nature of the class but I can create or not a custom class, list of instances of this class.

```
import SwiftUI

public class User: NSObject,Codable,ObservableObject {
    var username : String
    
    public override init() {
        self.username = "VOID"
    }
    public func setUsername(username:String){
        self.username=username
    }
}

var uad1:User = .init()
var uad2:User = .init()

var listUR: [User] = []

struct listM: View {
    init() {
        uad1.setUsername(username: "user1")
        listUR.append(uad1)
        
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        LazyVStack {
            ForEach(listUR.indices) { i in
                Text(verbatim: listUR[i].username)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        addElement()
                    }
                    .onAppear(){
                        print(i)
                    }
            }
        }
    }
    private func addElement(){
        uad2.setUsername(username: "user2")
        listUR.append(uad2)
        
    }
}
```

If I use `@State` Objects for the list, nothing gets displayed. As a list, first element is displayed but not the second when tap gesture. Trying to use Observed objects but can not loop ForEach. Please note that I need the `i` index on tap.

Comment: Try the [Apple SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui) all of this is pretty basic stuff

Comment: Thank you but before asking i searched but couldn t find something similar enough that i can adapt it

Comment: Does `User` need to be a class - can it be a struct instead?

Answer (score 0):

Your Users `Array` has to be `@State` in the `View`.

```
class User: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
  var id: UUID = UUID()
  var name: String

  init(name: String) {
    self.name = name
  }
}

struct ContentView: View {
  @State var users: [User] = [User(name: "VOID"), User(name: "VOID")]

  var body: some View {
    List {
      ForEach(users) { user in
        HStack { // <-- Use an HStack and add a Spacer so the cell goes to the edge
          Text(user.name)
          Spacer()
        }
        .contentShape(Rectangle()) // <-- Add a contentShape so the whole cell is tappable
        .onTapGesture {
          addUser()
        }
      }
    }
  }

  private func addUser() {
    users.append(User(name: "user\(users.count + 1)"))
  }
}
```